# Tensorflow installs & imports properly yet throws exceptions when trying to use

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have trouble using tensorflow. It seems to install and import properly. However when I call it, the interpreter throws an extended litany of exceptions with abridgment given below.

I'm using OS X El Capitan v 10.11.6
Macbook Pro (15" mid 2009)
2,8 GHz Intel Core Duo with
8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3 and
NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256MB

Python 3.7.1

with Jupyter notebook, Anaconda, pip etc. updated

The code (on Jupyter notebook)

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
```

Gives these exceptions

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-5e683e1280ff>", line 2, in <module>
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2018, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

# A lot more exceptions between these lines

...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   2017                         # in the engines. This should return a list of strings.
-> 2018                         stb = value._render_traceback_()
   2019                     except Exception:

AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_code(self, code_obj, result, async_)
   3282             if result is not None:
   3283                 result.error_in_exec = sys.exc_info()[1]
-> 3284             self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
   3285         else:
   3286             outflag = False

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   2019                     except Exception:
   2020                         stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(etype,
-> 2021                                             value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
   2022 
   2023                     self._showtraceback(etype, value, stb)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1377         self.tb = tb
   1378         return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
-> 1379             self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1380 
   1381 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1280             # Verbose modes need a full traceback
   1281             return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
-> 1282                 self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
   1283             )
   1284         elif mode == 'Minimal':

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1142         exception = self.get_parts_of_chained_exception(evalue)
   1143         if exception:
-> 1144             formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
   1145             etype, evalue, etb = exception
   1146         else:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load an MNIST datset, the syntax is:
`tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data`

For eg: `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path='mnist.npz')`

You can refer this page:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. However the problem persists with the same exceptions as before.

Comment: Did you specify a path?