# Anaconda not loading Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, anaconda3

Clean install of Windows10 with updates(iCore 5, 8Gb, 64bit). Installed Antivirus and Firewall. Installed Docker and pulled Tensorflow image and successfully created containers that works perfectly.
Then I downloaded and installed the latest Anaconda 64bit for Windows with all default settings on the host system. No python was installed before the time on the host system. 
In the PATH I moved "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps" down the list otherwise the python.exe inside this folder is default. 
Here is a pic of the PATH variables on the host system.

[Screenshot of PATH on host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UOuA.png)

On the host I did a pip upgrade and installed tensorflow successfully, but as you can see below when I try to import I get this error. 
I think it is specific to Anaconda as I'm not getting this in the docker container, with only Tensorflow and Jupyter Notebook installed.

Have already looked at [Request1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53962/dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-import-keras-using-bac) and [Request2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029836/tensorflow-installs-imports-properly-yet-throws-exceptions-when-trying-to-use) that is similar in output but with no answers.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

```
(base) C:\Users\DNN>where python
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

(base) C:\Users\DNN>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score -1):

Managed to get some info on the Tensorflow Github release notes which I tried and it worked for me.

Installed the VSRedis as per article below, restarted and my Tensorflow was working on the host.

My Docker container worked because the host image is Linux, but here my host pc is Windows and needs the following it seems. Just a pity they don't include this in the Anaconda install. Really had to go fish for this one.

**From the Github Release notes:** [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases)

> **Windows users**: Officially-released tensorflow Pip packages are now built with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 in order to take advantage of the new /d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions compiler flag. To use these new packages, you must install "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019", available from Microsoft's website [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

[MS Visual Studio Redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)